# XML multidimentional array php from URL

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm breaking my head about this one for 2 days now, so I hope someone can help a bit.

I need the data from an XML, which I get from a website. The code returns a nice list, but missing the time array (array from an array).
Here is my code :

```
<?php 
$url="http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/WindForecasting.v1.svc/GetForecastGraphDataXml?beginDate=2015-05-13&endDate=2015-05-18&isOffshore=&isEliaConnected=";
echo $url;

$sxml = Simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump($sxml);
foreach ($sxml ->ForecastGraphItems ->WindForecastingGraphItem as $type){
    echo 'FC ';
    echo $type ->Forecast."<br>";
    echo 'LF ';
    echo $type ->LoadFactor."<br>";
    echo 'DT ';
    echo $type ->Time[0]->DateTime;
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'BID ';
    echo $type ->Bid."<br>";
    echo 'RA '; 
    echo $type ->RunningAverage."<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

The XML format I get when I just manualy open the website looks like the code below, or check the Original website : http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/WindForecasting.v1.svc/GetForecastGraphDataXml?beginDate=2015-05-13&endDate=2015-05-18&isOffshore=&isEliaConnected=

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<WindForecastingGraphDataResponse xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Elia.PublicationService.DomainInterface.WindForecasting.v1">

    <ErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
    <ForecastGraphItems>
        <WindForecastingGraphItem>
            <Bid>No</Bid>
            <Forecast>571.45</Forecast>
            <LoadFactor>0.32</LoadFactor>
            <RunningAverage>585.59</RunningAverage>
            <Time xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <a:DateTime>2015-05-12T22:00:00Z</a:DateTime>
                <a:OffsetMinutes>120</a:OffsetMinutes>
            </Time>
        </WindForecastingGraphItem>
        <WindForecastingGraphItem>
            <Bid>No</Bid>
            <Forecast>562.95</Forecast>
            <LoadFactor>0.32</LoadFactor>
            <RunningAverage>578.47</RunningAverage>
            <Time xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <a:DateTime>2015-05-12T22:15:00Z</a:DateTime>
                <a:OffsetMinutes>120</a:OffsetMinutes>
            </Time>
```

Now, when I `var_dump($sxml)`, or if I try to get it, the sub-array for TIME dropped out...  (see below).
I also tried `foreach ($sxml ->ForecastGraphItems ->WindForecastingGraphItem  -> Time as $time){ ...`, which worked, but returned empty.

Anyone can help why the 'time' array is empty  ?

Below the echo for `var_dump`:

> http://publications.elia.be/Publications/Publications/WindForecasting.v1.svc/GetForecastGraphDataXml?beginDate=2015-05-13&endDate=2015-05-18&isOffshore=&isEliaConnected=object(SimpleXMLElement)#1
>   (2) { ["ErrorMessage"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { }
>   ["ForecastGraphItems"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
>   ["WindForecastingGraphItem"]=> array(481) { [0]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (5) { ["Bid"]=> string(2) "No"
>   ["Forecast"]=> string(6) "571.45" ["LoadFactor"]=> string(4) "0.32"
>   ["RunningAverage"]=> string(6) "585.59" ["Time"]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#485 (0) { } } [1]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (5) { ["Bid"]=> string(2) "No"
>   ["Forecast"]=> string(6) "562.95" ["LoadFactor"]=> string(4) "0.32"
>   ["RunningAverage"]=> string(6) "578.47" ["Time"]=>
>   object(SimpleXMLElement)#485 (0) { } }

Comment: it is because of the namespace `a` in `<a:DateTime>`

Answer (score 0):

As michi has commented already you'd like to get access to elements that are in a different namespace:

```xml
            <Time xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <a:DateTime>2015-05-12T22:15:00Z</a:DateTime>
                <a:OffsetMinutes>120</a:OffsetMinutes>
            </Time>
```

The `<Time>` element sets for all it's children the prefix *`a`* to the XML namespace *`http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System`*. You're interested in two children with that prefix:

```xml
                <a:DateTime>2015-05-12T22:15:00Z</a:DateTime>
                <a:OffsetMinutes>120</a:OffsetMinutes>
```

You do this by telling the namespace of the children you're interested in, e.g. for the first element:

```
$type ->Time->children('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System')->DateTime;
```

And that's it already.

Now to correct some misunderstanding:

- that is not an array
- yes, `var_dump` told you it's one, but it's just not.
- `var_dump` and `print_r` are not particular useful with **SimpleXMLElement** as they lie about it. `SimpleXMLElement::asXML()` shows you the concrete XML, always.

Comment: Indeed this was the sollution !

Comment: Hi @dwindey1: As you're a new user, please take a quick look here on how accepting an answer works (part of the vote system on Stackoverflow): [Meta: How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)